# js Object Array causing function not defined

Tags: multidimensional-array, json

Ok, I'm having a hard time trying to create an object array that I can use within a select box...

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var oTranslators = {{"bosniancroatianserbian" : null} , {"dutch" : {"name":"willemjan","id":2}} , {"german" : {"name":"chilly","id":11}} , {"german_informal" : {"name":"Boantio","id":1640}} , {"greek" : null} , {"hungarian" : {"name":"Rudi","id":69}} , {"norwegian" : null} , {"russian" : {"name":"Bugo","id":43}} , {"spanish" : {"name":"Diego Andr\u00e9s","id":413}} };
function lang_switch(val)
{
    if (val == 1)
        document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML = '<select name="lang_name" onchange="trans_switch(this.selectedIndex);"><option value="bosniancroatianserbian">Bosnian/Croatian/Serbian</option><option value="dutch">Dutch</option><option value="german">German</option><option value="german_informal">German Informal</option><option value="greek">Greek</option><option value="hungarian">Hungarian</option><option value="norwegian">Norwegian</option><option value="russian">Russian</option><option value="spanish">Spanish</option></select><label for="translator">Translator: <select name="translator" id="translator"></select></label>';
    else
        document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML = '';
}
function trans_switch(oBName)
{
    document.upload.translator.options.length = 0;
    var oBoard = oTranslators[oBName];
    for (var i = 0; i < oBoard.length; i++) {
        translator.options[translator.options.length] = new Option(oBoard.name, oBoard.id, false, false);
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://mydomain.com/myaction.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <dl class="settings">
        <dt>
            <strong>Choose a file to upload:</strong>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="file" name="dp_file" size="38" class="input_file" />
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <select name="down_area" onchange="lang_switch(this.value);">
                <option value="0">Main Download</option>
                <option value="1">Language Packs</option>
            </select>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <div id="lang"></div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div style="text-align: right;"><input name="upload" type="submit" value="Upload" class="button_submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Basically, I am getting error stating that `lang_switch` is undefined, which is nuts, because it's right there.  Is there something wrong with my object array?  Did I not define it properly?  This is coming from a `json_encode`, but it is a multidimensional array and I had to fix it a little, so am using this php code to fix it, within a for loop:

```
$oTrans = '';
$i = 0;
    foreach($context['languages'] as $lang => $language)
    {
        $i++;
        $oTrans .= '{"' . $lang . '" : ' . json_encode($language['translator'][$lang]) . '} ' . (count($context['languages']) == $i ? '};' : ', ');
```

Am I not doing this right?  What is wrong with the `oTranslators` object array above?

Comment: Where is the code that contains `lang_switch()`? Is it directly in the file or imported? Typically an undefined error means you are either not importing the file properly or you have a syntax error affecting the definition of the method (crashing before you define the method).

Comment: `function lang_switch()` is being put into the head of the document.  When I do a view source on the page, I can see it defined in the head of the document within opening and closing script tags.  Yet, I am getting error stating that this is not defined!  If I remove the `oTranslators` variable, I no longer get an error and the script works fine.

Comment: Can you post all of the javascript preceding this method, or better yet, put it in a jsFiddle using dummy data.

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with the `oTranslators` variable, because when I remove it, the script works fine, without any errors.

Comment: Give me a minute to debug your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing with your code is that while you are trying to make a javascript-array of objects, you are attempting to initialize the array using object-brackets: `{`.

The result will give you an error, because you cannot initialize an object in the following way:

```
{{Prop1:val}, {Prop2:val}};
```

It would need to be the following:

```
{Prop1:val, Prop2:val};
```

Therefore, to fix your array, all you need to do is replace the first `{` and last `}` with array brackets, `[` and `]`:

```
[{"bosniancroatianserbian" : null} , {"dutch" : {"name":"willemjan","id":2}} , {"german" : {"name":"chilly","id":11}} , {"german_informal" : {"name":"Boantio","id":1640}} , {"greek" : null} , {"hungarian" : {"name":"Rudi","id":69}} , {"norwegian" : null} , {"russian" : {"name":"Bugo","id":43}} , {"spanish" : {"name":"Diego Andr\u00e9s","id":413}} ];
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem exactly!